# Align background image to the right of a table td element

Tags: html, css

I have a table with td elements holding text, left-aligned as normal.
Under certain conditions, I am adorning my td elements with a background image (denoted by a tick).

My css element to attempt to achieve this is:

```css
td.entered {
  background: url(../images/tick.png) no-repeat;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class "entered">Here is some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, no matter how I adjust this CSS, I don't get what I want, and the tick image appears in the centre of the td.
Is there a way to make this image float on the right, so that it interferes less with the text in that cell?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan What is missing from this question?

Comment: Html, Running code with some imgur tick, Images of expected results

Comment: Yes, since the solution could be to NOT use a background image like I posted

Comment: So I guessed correctly, but it was a guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```css
td.entered {
  width: 200px;
  background: url("https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/check-tick-icon/tick-mark-icon-png-7.png") right -1px no-repeat ;
  background-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="entered">Here is some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Without images

```css
td.entered {
  width: 200px;
}

span.ticked:after {
  content: "✓";
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="entered">Here is some text<span class="ticked"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Dynamic demo

JavaScript to show what the cell looks like before and after the span has ticked

```js
document.querySelector(".entered").addEventListener("click",function() {
  this.querySelector("span").classList.add("ticked");
})
```

```css
td.entered {
  width: 200px;
}

span.ticked:after {
  content: "✓";
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="entered">Here is some text<span></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach. I could drop some iconography into this span through the CSS.

Comment: See updated code with background placement and size